# Command in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a simple question about the terminal (on os x)
When I get an error in the terminal, the cursor don't show up and every commands I type are not proceed.

The last line i get is :

```
2012-06-22 14:35:36.905 firefox-bin[65232:d07] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary.
```

Do I have to restart the terminal or is there a way to pass trough ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may quit the program that you launched with < Ctrl-C > (for other application < Ctrl-D > might do the trick)